# Getting AttributeError when using inherited class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having some trouble with a Python script for data management/visualization.

I am defining some classes to help with the data bounding. However, I am encountering a problem when trying to define a class that inherits from another one:

```
import netCDF4 as netcdf
import numpy as np

class cellData:
    
    def __init__(self, cellNetCDF, gridNetCDF):
        self.cellNetCDF = cellNetCDF
        self.gridNetCDF = gridNetCDF
        
        self.X = np.array(cellNetCDF.variables['X'])
        self.Y = np.array(cellNetCDF.variables['Y'])
        self.neighbrArray = np.array(grid.variables['minLevelCellsNghbrIds'])
        
        self.arrayList = {}
        for var in cellNetCDF.variables.values():
            self.arrayList[var.name] = np.array(var[:])
            
        self.noCells = cellNetCDF.dimensions['dim0'].size
        
    def cellCoord(self, cellId, direction):
        if direction == 0:
            return self.X[cellId]    
        elif direction == 1:
            return self.Y[cellId]
    
    def neighbrId(self, cellId, direction):
            return self.neighbrArray[4 * cellId + direction]
        
    def getVariable(self, cellId, var):
        variableNum = invertedMap[var]
        return self.arrayList[variableNum][cellId]
    
    def applyMask(self, maskArray):
        return maskedCellData(self, maskArray)

class maskedCellData(cellData):
    
    def __init__(self, cellDataObject, maskArray):
        self.X[:] = cellDataObject.X[:] * maskArray[:]  
        self.Y[:] = cellDataObject.Y[:] * maskArray[:]
        
        self.arrayList = {}
        for var in cellDataObject.arrayList:
            self.arrayList[var] = cellDataObject.arrayList[var] * maskArray
            

def getMask(cellDataObject, point1, direction): 
    
    noCells = cellDataObject.noCells
    
    maskArray = np.zeros(noCells)
    
    for cellId in range(0, noCells - 1):
        nghbrId = cellDataObject.neighbrId(cellId, direction + 2)
        if(nghbrId == -1): continue
        if (cellDataObject.cellCoord(cellId, direction) - point1 < 0 ) & (cellDataObject.cellCoord(nghbrId, direction) - point1 > 0):
            maskArray[cellId] = 1
            
    return maskArray

Map = {'variables0' : 'u',
           'variables1' : 'v',
           'variables2' : 'rho',
           'variables3' : 'p',
           'variables4' : 'YH2',
           'variables5' : 'YH',
           'variables6' : 'YO',
           'variables7' : 'YO2',
           'variables8' : 'YOH',
           'variables9' : 'YH2O',
           'variables10' : 'YHO2',
           'variables11' : 'YH2O2',
           'variables12' : 'YN',
           'variables13' : 'YNH',
           'variables14' : 'YNH2',
           'variables15' : 'YNH3',
           'variables16' : 'YNNH',
           'variables17' : 'YNO',
           'variables18' : 'YNO2',
           'variables19' : 'YN2O',
           'variables20' : 'YHNO',
           'variables21' : 'YN2'
    }

invertedMap = {v: k for k, v in Map.items()}

f = netcdf.Dataset("pressureOutput/restartVariables_2.Netcdf","r")
grid = netcdf.Dataset("pressureOutput/grid.Netcdf","r")

cellData1 = cellData(f, grid)

maskArray = getMask(cellData1, 0, 0)

maskedCellData = maskedCellData(cellData1, maskArray)
```

When I let the code run, I get the following error:

```
> 
  File "/Users/borjapedro/Desktop/TFM/Python/1DSlice.py", line 102, in <module>
    maskedCellData = maskedCellData(cellData1, maskArray)

  File "/Users/borjapedro/Desktop/TFM/Python/1DSlice.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.X[:] = cellDataObject.X[:] * maskArray[:]

AttributeError: 'maskedCellData' object has no attribute 'X'
```

What is my mistake here?

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step. Also, when asking about errors, be sure to post the ***full*** error traceback

Comment: Note that classes should have their first characters caitalised to tell them from functions

Comment: You are doing `self.X[:]` which tries to assign to `X` which doesn't exist. Did you forget to call `super` in the `__init__`?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Please [edit] your question and add the complete traceback.

Comment: I edited the error message. I will read about the super function, maybe therein lies the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, the super function was the problem. I think I had some clear misunderstandings about how class inheritance works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python the initialization of base classes is not automatic but has to be explicitely asked by the programmer. I allows to completely replace the initialization of a base class, or to choose exactly when to call it. So here you should initialize the base class *before* changing its values:

```
class maskedCellData(cellData):
    
    def __init__(self, cellDataObject, maskArray):
        super().__init__(cellDataObject.cellNetCDF, cellDataObject.gridNetCDF) # base class init
        self.X[:] = cellDataObject.X[:] * maskArray[:]  
        self.Y[:] = cellDataObject.Y[:] * maskArray[:]
        
        self.arrayList = {}
        for var in cellDataObject.arrayList:
            self.arrayList[var] = cellDataObject.arrayList[var] * maskArray
```

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem. I did not fully understand how the initialization of derived classes actually happened. Thank you for your hindsight!

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

```
class cellData(cellNetCDF):
```